# td mimic label behaviour regarding checkbox

Tags: css, html-table, label

Is it possible through css only to force text inside table cell (td) to toggle checkbox, just like it occurs for text inside label tag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a `label` to control checking an input field. Hide the `input` field and use the `for` attribute on the `label` to connect it to the `id` of the `input` field.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label:after {
  content: ' (checked)';
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="foo"><label for="foo">click</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you but it is not what I'm looking for, what I'm asking is if there is any css attribute that can make td behave like label and toggle checkbox when clicked, with no label tag at all.

Comment: @fcaserio nope, CSS is for display only. the label tag is the only element that can bind to a form input and mimic the input behavior. You could always write a javascript click event handler for the table element and use that to manipulate an input checkbox.